# I get no sound in Game in UE 5

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Same project ToonTanks had sound normally in UE4 but when I migrated to UE5 there is no projectile sound.

In projectile.h I declare a sound like this

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category="combat") 
USoundBase* LaunchSound;
```

and I set it in the blueprint then in projectile.cpp BeginPlay I play the sound like this

```
if (LaunchSound) { 
UGameplayStatics::PlaySoundAtLocation(this, LaunchSound, GetActorLocation());
}
```

Editor output sound normally when I press on the stop button also I tried FPS demo it has sound in game normally. I debugged this game and the execution go inside `if` but no sound. Any advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using these steps:

```
1-Delete the folder Intermediate
2-Right click the uproject file and select generate vs files
3-open rider and choose for ex development editor build
4-wait until rider update source files
5-build from rider 
6-open UE5 editor and run and sound work as expected.
```